# For matrix $A$ and any invertible matrix $C$, $CA$ has zero diag. Prove that $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a matrix so that for all invertible matrices $C$, the diagonal entries of $CA$ are all $0$. Prove that $A=0$.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Do you now elementary matrices?

Comment: Is there any method without use of elementary matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $(1,1)$ coefficient of $CA$ is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n c_{1k}a_{k1}
$$
(with obvious, I hope, meaning of the symbols).

Choose $C$ as the matrix that has the first row equal to
$$
[0\quad 0\quad\dots\quad0\quad \underset{\substack{\uparrow\\h}}{1}\quad 0
\quad\dots\quad 0]
$$
(zero on all columns except $1$ on the $h$-th column) and the other rows of the identity below the first. Such a matrix $C$ has rank $n$, so it's invertible. Now, by assumption,
$$
0=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{1k}a_{k1}=a_{h1}
$$
Thus all coefficients in the first column of $A$ are zero, because we can do this for any value $1\le h\le n$.

Do similarly for the other columns.

For example, if $n=4$, we can consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\quad(h=2);
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\quad(h=4)
$$

Comment: Give an example of $C$, please.

Comment: @MathMan Added the examples

Comment: In your example, for $h=2$ we have $CA=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & a_{12} & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{21} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & a_{33} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & a_{44}
\end{array}
\right)$. Is it true?

Comment: @MathMan No; you get the same matrix as $A$, but with the first and second rows swapped.

Comment: oh yes, excuse me please :)

Answer (score 5):

By multiplication with the identity matrix, we immediately see that $A$ has only zeroes on its diagonal. Note further that we can multiply an invertible matrix from the left which results in a permutation of two rows, see *[elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-switching_transformations)*. Since permutation still results in zeroes on the diagonal, $A$ must contain only zeroes.

Comment: More precisely, permuting the first row with any row shows that the first row of $A$ contains only zeros. Continuing with the permutations which switch with the second row, also the second row must only contain zeros, and so on, this argument works for all rows.